# controlling size of QItemDelegate dynamically

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a couple of questions regarding the sizes of [QItemDelegates](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html) in a [QListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html):

I have a [QListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html) using a [QItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html) which renders a widget in the delegate's custom [paint()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html#paint) method like so:

```
self.thumbnail = MyCustomWidget()
self.thumbnail.render(painter, QtCore.QPoint(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y()))
```

This, however, shows the item with a 250x260 image in a [QListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html), even though the [MyCustomWidget().sizeHint()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop) is 250x250 and it's maximumSize() returns 250x250 as well.

I found that the culprit is the [QListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html)'s [spacing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html#spacing-prop), which I had set to 10. If I set the [spacing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html#spacing-prop) to 100, I still get the [QItemDelegates](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html) size of 250x260, but if I just don't use [setSpacing()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html#spacing-prop) at all it renders as expected at 250x250.
The [spacing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html#spacing-prop) seems to alter the [option](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstyleoptionviewitem.html).rect that is passed into the paint method, causing the incorrect size.
I do need that [spacing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html#spacing-prop), so I'm a bit confused why the [QListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html)'s spacing alters the [QItemDelegates](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html)'s size? Is this a bug?

I can work around this by rendering a [QPixmap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html) first, then have the [painter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html) draw the [QPixmap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html) instead of rendering to the [painter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html) directly:

```
self.thumbnail = MyCustomWidget()
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self.thumbnail.size())
self.thumbnail.render(pixmap)
painter.drawPixmap(option.rect.topLeft(), pixmap)
```

This yields 250x250 images which is what I need, but I don't understand why the first method doesn't render the correct size when I use [setSpacing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html#spacing-prop)?!

Now, the bigger challenge is how to dynamically scale the size of the [QItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html)'s via a [QSlider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qslider.html):
I have a [QSlider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qslider.html) in the [QListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html) that is supposed to scale the items so the user can chose to see smaller but more items in the current view. I tested the resizing of a standalone instance of MyCustomWidget() and it works just fine.

However, the delegates won't scale as expected. This is my delegate code:
class Delegate(QtGui.QItemDelegate):

```
def __init__(self, parent = None):

    super(Delegate, self).__init__(parent)
    self.scaleValue = 100 # size in percent (as returned by QSlider)

def paint(self, painter, option, index):
    proxyModel = index.model()
    item = proxyModel.sourceModel().itemFromIndex(proxyModel.mapToSource(index))
    self.thumbnail = ElementThumbnail(item)
    self.thumbnail.scale(self.scaleValue)

    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self.thumbnail.size())
    self.thumbnail.render(pixmap)
    painter.drawPixmap(option.rect.topLeft() * self.scaleValue / 100.0, pixmap)

    super(Delegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)

def setScaleValue(self, value):
    self.scaleValue = value

def sizeHint(self, option, index):
    return ElementThumbnail.thumbSize  * self.scaleValue / 100.0
```

and in the [QListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html) I am using this slot connected to the slider's valueChanges signal:

```
def scaleThumbnails(self, value):
    self.itemDelegate().setScaleValue(value)
    self.update()
```

The result is that the [QSlider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qslider.html) will crop the [QItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html)s but not scale them, because the [QItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html)'s [sizeHint()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html#sizeHint) is only called when the [QListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html) is first shown.
Additionally, I need to make sure that when the widgets are (eventually) scaled down, the layout of [QListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html) is recalculated and more items are fit inside the visible area.

So in a nutshell my questions are:

1. How can I scale [QItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemdelegate.html)s dynamically inside a [QListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html)?
2. How can I force the [QListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html) to recalculate it's layout after the delegate size has been changed?

**edit: as for issue 2: [QAbstractItemView.doItemsLayout](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QAbstractItemView.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QAbstractItemView.doItemsLayout) seems to do the trick. Still wondering about issue 1 though**

Thanks,
frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the context of my code that was the issue, not the delegate.
I was scaling the widget before rendering it to a pixmap, which of course made the editor scale properly, but not the item when it wasn't in edit state.
So the solution is simply to scale the pixmap after rendering it from the widget, e.g.:

```
scaledPixmap = pixmap.scaled(pixmap.size() * self.scaleValue / 100.0)
painter.drawPixmap(option.rect.topLeft(), scaledPixmap)
```